# Addition of row values using query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have one query which provides the following data:

```
 revenue      total     period       User
 1111          150      07/2011      User1
 2513          120      09/2011      User1
 500           170      11/2011      User1
```

My query is :

```
SELECT sum(c.planned_revenue)as revenue, u.expected_target as total ,p.name as period,u.name as user 
FROM crm_lead c, res_users u, account_period p, account_fiscalyear f 
WHERE c.user_id = u.id and u.id = 10
      and p.name=to_char(c.create_date,'mm/yyyy') and p.fiscalyear_id = f.id and f.id = GROUP BY p.name,u.expected_target,u.name
ORDER BY p.name
```

I want to get the values as following (commutative addition):

```
revenue      total     period       User
1111          150      07/2011      User1
3624          120      09/2011      User1
4124          170      11/2011      User1
```

What change need to get the above output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tagged your question with PostgreSQL, the running total can easily be achieved using a windowing function.

It's not clear to me from your question if the running total is per user or per period, but the following might give you a starting point:

```
SELECT sum(c.planned_revenue) over (partition by u.name order by c.create_date) as revenue, 
       u.expected_target as total,
       p.name as period,
       u.name as user 
FROM crm_lead c, res_users u, account_period p, account_fiscalyear f 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY p.name
```

The part that is responsible for creating the running total, is the `over(...)` clause. By supplying an `ORDER BY` in it you change the aggregate function from an "overal" aggregation to a "running" aggregation.

I'm not sure I understood completely what the "grouping level" for the aggregate should be. I guess you want the running total per user and that's what the `partition by u.name` is doing. If you want to get the running total for a different "group", just change the definition in there.

Note that the GROUP BY is no longer necessary once you use the windowing function.

More information about windowing functions can be found in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Btw: I would recommend to use explicit `JOIN`s instead of the implicit joining in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery with variable, for example -

```
SELECT @rev:=@rev + revenue AS revenue, total, period, user FROM (
  SELECT SUM(c.planned_revenue) AS revenue, u.expected_target AS total...
  ...
  ...
  ) t1,
  (SELECT @rev :=0) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a running total. Without actually checking it, you need something like the following:

```
select (select sum(cl.planned_revenue) from crm_lead where cl.user_id = c.user_id and cl.create_date <= c.create_date) as revenue, u.expected_target as total, p.name as period, u.name as user  
from crm_lead c, res_users u, account_period p, account_fiscalyear f  
where c.user_id = u.id and u.id = 10  
and p.name = to_char(c.create_date, 'mm/yyyy') and p.fiscalyear_id = f.id  
group by p.name, u.expected_target, u.name  
order by p.name
```

The query to retrieve the running total needs to link to the main query for the appropriate user etc and include all dates up to and including the current period. So there may be a tweak required but that's the principle